Predestination and 1 Timothy 2:4
I'm an evangelical myself (Anglican) and I wonder how could we deal with this apparent contradiction.
The question is whether there is a clash between the concept of predestination and 1 Timothy 2:4. Predestination, especially as articulated in certain interpretations of Calvinism, suggests that God has foreordained some people to salvation and others to damnation. In contrast, 1 Timothy 2:4 states, "God desires all people to be saved and to come to the knowledge of the truth".
Predestination
Predestination, as understood in Calvinist theology, is the doctrine that God has chosen certain individuals for salvation before the foundation of the world. This choice is not based on any foreseen merit or action on the part of the individual but solely on God's sovereign will. This is often coupled with the doctrine of election, which holds that God's grace is extended to those He has chosen, and they will inevitably come to faith.
1 Timothy 2:4
1 Timothy 2:4 is often cited by those who argue against the Calvinist interpretation of predestination. The verse suggests a universal salvific will, indicating that God's desire is for all people to be saved and to come to the knowledge of the truth. This seems to conflict with the idea that God has only predestined a select group for salvation.

related: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/90992/22319

also related: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/71156/what-is-the-reformed-protestant-understanding-of-gods-permissive-will-his-sove

Your ask "how could we deal with this apparent contradiction?"  I may be simply misunderstanding your question but who do you mean by "we"?  Anglican evangelicals or people who accept the view of Calvin?

Well, I'm sorry for making this so dependent on nominations. The question is about conflict of this passage and the idea of predestination. I presented myself as Anglican because I really understand modern Anglicanism (as many others) as a way to harmonize all nominations, and don't want to contradict Calvinism.

This question is similar to: According to Reformed Theology, what is the exegetical basis for the claim that 1 Timothy 2:4 means "all kinds of people"?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Neither the Title nor anything in the Body contain an actual question.  What exactly are you asking? As worded, it seems to say that the Calvinist belief contradicts the Bible, for which the obvious answer is: since the Bible is the ultimate authority, the Calvinists must be wrong. Is that really what you want to know, and if so, why wasn't it already obvious?

I pressupose the Calvinists read the Bible, Ray Butterworth, so the question is not so obvious. Anyway, some gentle people showed me a plethora of other passages that make us think that really there may be predestination.

@AlfredoMaranca, my point was that you didn't actually ask a question, and my example was to illustrate how one could easily misrepresent what you had intended to ask.

There is a point of interest I hold onto that resolves the problem of ‘God‘s love for all’ and ‘his choice of some in election’, that surprisingly both Luther and Calvin express in their own way and goes largely untoiced.
It is important to allow apparent contradictions in our reason to fully grasp the gospel by our faith. How can any believe the gospel if they do not believe the gospel is offered to all? Preaching the gospel to an unbeliever is a form of deception in my mind, if it is not offered and believed without any consideration of the doctrine of election. Sinners believe Christ died for them because they believe he died for all.  Also, how can we deny God‘s individual election of souls from eternity when it is so clearly stated in so many parts of scripture? We can believe God loves all men and only saved some by recognising the way both Luther and Calvin allowed it in faith.  The truth is finally not in a balance of two extremes but in both extremes. God loves all extremenly and God will only save the elect, without a chance of an exception. This I can believe by faith in he that is so much greater than my mind.
Calvin expresses it in the sense of God having ’two wills‘. Here he iis talking about Chrit‘s longing to save the Jews that reject him:

The will of God, which is here mentioned, must be judged from the
result. For since by his word he calls all men indiscriminately to
salvation, and since the end of preaching is, that all should betake
themselves to his guardianship and protection, it may justly be said
that he wills to gather all to himself. It is not, therefore, the
secret purpose of God, but his will, which is manifested by the nature
of the word, that is here described; for, undoubtedly, whomsoever he
efficaciously wills to gather, he inwardly draws by his Spirit, and
does not merely invite by the outward voice of man. If it be objected,
that it is absurd to suppose the existence of two wills in God, I
reply, we fully believe that his will is simple and one; but as our
minds do not fathom the deep abyss of secret election, in
accommodation to the capacity of our weakness, the will of God is
exhibited to us in two ways. And I am astonished at the obstinacy of
some people, who, when in many passages of Scripture they meet with
that figure of speech (Î±Ì“Î½Î¸ÏÏ‰Ï€Î¿Ï€Î±ÌÎ¸ÎµÎ¹Î±) which
attributes to God human feelings, take no offence, but in this case
alone refuse to admit it. But as I have elsewhere treated this subject
fully, that I may not be unnecessarily tedious, I only state briefly
that, whenever the doctrine, which is the standard of union, is
brought forward, God wills to gather all, that all who do not come may
be inexcusable.
Calvin, J., & Pringle, W. (2010). Commentary on a Harmony of the
Evangelists Matthew, Mark, and Luke (Vol. 3, p. 109).

Here he is talking about John 3:16

That whosoever believeth in him may not perish. What a praise of
faith, that it delivers us from eternal destruction! Christ means
clearly that even though we are born for death, by faith in him we are
offered a sure deliverance from it; therefore, we ought not to fear
the death which still awaits us. And now he adds a universal call,
inviting all men without exception to share in life, and leaving
unbelievers without an excuse. The word world, in the previous phrase,
has the same significance. Even though there is nothing in the world
worthy of God’s favor, he shows himself gracious toward the whole
world, and he invites all men without exception to faith in Christ,
which is nothing less than entering into Life.
On the other hand, let us remember that while life is promised in Christ to all who believe, only a small part of the people are
believers. Christ is indeed presented to all, but God opens the eyes
of the elect alone, and enables them by faith to seek after him. The
wonderful effect of faith is also seen in our receiving Christ from
the Father, who has in Christ truly freed us from the punishment of
eternal death, and made us heirs of eternal life; for by the sacrifice
of his death, Christ has expiated our sins; and now nothing keeps God
from acknowledging us as his sons. Since therefore faith embraces
Christ, together with the efficacy of his death and the fruit of his
resurrection, it is no wonder that by faith likewise we obtain the
very Life of Christ.
Haroutunian, J., & Smith, L. P. (1958). Calvin: Commentaries (pp.
193–194). Westminster Press

Here he is talking about how God doe snot delight in the death of the wicked:

Besides, it is not surprising that our eyes should be blinded by
intense light, so that we cannot certainly judge how God wishes all
to be saved, and yet has devoted all the reprobate to eternal
destruction, and wishes them to perish. While we look now through a
glass darkly, we should be content with the measure of our own
intelligence. (1 Cor. 13:12.) When we shall be like God, and see him
face to face, then what is now obscure will then become plain. But
since captious men torture this and similar passages, it will be
needful to refute them shortly, since it can be done without trouble.
God is said not to wish the death of a sinner. How so? since he wishes all to be converted.  Now we must see how God wishes all to
be converted; for repentance is surely his peculiar gift: as it is his
office to create men, so it is his province to renew them, and restore
his image within them. For this reason we are said to be his
workmanship, that is, his fashioning. (Eph. 2:10.) Since, therefore,
repentance is a kind of second creation, it follows that it is not in
man’s power; and if it is equally in God’s power to convert men as
well as to create them, it follows that the reprobate are not
converted, because God does not wish their conversion; for if he
wished it he could do it: and hence it appears that he does not wish
it. But again they argue foolishly, since God does not wish all to be
converted, he is himself deceptive, and nothing can be certainly
stated concerning his paternal benevolence. But this knot is easily
untied; for he does not leave us in suspense when he says, that he
wishes all to be saved. Why so? for if no one repents without finding
God propitious, then this sentence is filled up. But we must remark
that God puts on a twofold character: for he here wishes to be taken
at his word. As I have already said, the Prophet does not here dispute
with subtlety about his incomprehensible plans, but wishes to keep our
attention close to God’s word. Now, what are the contents of this
word? The law, the prophets, and the gospel. Now all are called to
repentance, and the hope of salvation is promised them when they
repent: this is true, since God rejects no returning sinner: he
pardons all without exception; meanwhile, this will of God which he
sets forth in his word does not prevent him from decreeing before the
world was created what he would do with every individual: and as I
have now said, the Prophet only shows here, that when we have been
converted we need not doubt that God immediately meets us and shows
himself propitious.
Calvin, J., & Myers, T. (2010). Commentary on the First Twenty
Chapters of the Book of the Prophet Ezekiel (Vol. 2, pp. 247–249).

Here he is refering to the verse you are asking about:

Hence we see the childish folly of those who represent this passage to
be opposed to predestination. “If God,” say they, “wishes all men
indiscriminately to be saved, it is false that some are predestinated
by his eternal purpose to salvation, and others to perdition.” They
might have had some ground for saying this, if Paul were speaking here
about individual men; although even then we should not have wanted the
means of replying to their argument; for, although the will of God
ought not to be judged from his secret decrees, when he reveals them
to us by outward signs, yet it does not therefore follow that he has
not determined with himself what he intends to do as to every
individual man.
Calvin, J., & Pringle, W. (2010). Commentaries on the Epistles to
Timothy, Titus, and Philemon (p. 54).

Even beter to me is the way Luther describes the same thing, God‘s hidden will or himself and his revealed will or his word. In fact you see his method of thinking across many parts of his writings and is a fundamental character of his faith. Luther was preaching before Calvin. Some of Calvin’s ideas probably have actually come from Luther but we will never now to what degree.
He is here arguing against Erasmus who was trying to oppose predestination:

Diatribe, however, deceives herself in her ignorance by not making any >distinction between God preached and God hidden, that is,
between the Word of God and God himself. God does many things that he
does not disclose to us in his word; he also wills many things which
he does not disclose himself as willing in his word. Thus he does
not will the death of a sinner, according to his word; but he wills it
according to that inscrutable will of his. It is our business,
however, to pay attention to the word and leave that inscrutable will
alone, for we must be guided by the word and not by that inscrutable
will. After all, who can direct himself by a will completely
inscrutable and unknowable? It is enough to know simply that there is
a certain inscrutable will in God, and as to what, why, and how far it
wills, that is something we have no right whatever to inquire into,
hanker after, care about, or meddle with, but only to fear and adore.
It is therefore right to say, “If God does not desire our death, the fact that we perish must be imputed to our own will.” It is right,
I mean, if you speak of God as preached; for he wills all men to be
saved [1 Tim. 2:4], seeing he comes with the word of salvation to all,
and the fault is in the will that does not admit him, as he says in
Matthew 23[:37]: “How often would I have gathered your children, and
you would not!” But why that majesty of his does not remove or change
this defect of our will in all men, since it is not in man’s power to
do so, or why he imputes this defect to man, when man cannot help
having it, we have no right to inquire; and though you may do a lot of
inquiring, you will never find out. It is as Paul says in Romans
11[9:20]: “Who are you, to answer back to God?” Let these remarks
suffice for that passage of Ezekiel, and let us go on to the rest.
Luther, M. (1999). Luther’s works, vol. 33: Career of the Reformer III (J. J. Pelikan, H. C. Oswald, & H. T. Lehmann, Eds.; Vol. 33, p.
140). Fortress Press

Here are some similar thoughts in Romans:

This understanding of which he speaks is faith itself, or the
knowledge of the invisible things and the things which must be
believed. Therefore it is an understanding in concealment because
it deals with those things which a man cannot know of himself, as we
read John 14:6: “No one comes to the Father but by Me,” and again
(John 6:44): “No one can come to Me unless the Father â€¦ draws him,”
and to Peter (Matt. 16:17), “Blessed are you, Simon Bar-Jona! For
flesh and blood has not revealed this to you, but my Father who is in
heaven.” How, therefore, can those on the left, the ungodly and the
sensual, know this, because they regard only visible things? And how
can those on the right, who consider only their own opinion and give
weight only to that? Both groups put up a barrier for themselves and
establish a foreign obstacle blocking out the light of a clear
understanding of this matter.
Luther, M. (1999). Luther’s works, vol. 25: Lectures on Romans (J. J.
Pelikan, H. C. Oswald, & H. T. Lehmann, Eds.; Vol. 25, pp. 224–225).
Concordia Publishing House


For thus Is. 64:8 says: “Yet, O Lord, Thou art our Father; we are the
clay, and Thou art our potter; we are all the work of Thy hand.”
Therefore these people who do not have the Spirit flee and do not want
the works of God to be done but want to form themselves. But those who
have the Spirit are helped by Him. Thus they do not lose hope but have
confidence, even though they are aware of what goes contrary to what
they have so sincerely prayed for. For the work of God must be
hidden and never understood, even when it happens. But it is never
hidden in any other way than under that which appears contrary to our
conceptions and ideas. Hence Gabriel says to the Virgin: “The Holy
Spirit will come upon you,” that is, He will come upon you in a way
which is above what you think, “and the power of the Most High will
overshadow you” (Luke 1:35), that is, you will not understand, and
therefore do not ask how it will come to pass.
Luther, M. (1999). Luther’s works, vol. 25: Lectures on Romans (J. J.
Pelikan, H. C. Oswald, & H. T. Lehmann, Eds.; Vol. 25, p. 366).
Concordia Publishing House.


Some argue that God loves all humans and wants all humans to be saved. They take 1 Timothy 2:4 to mean 'all mankind' rather than 'all types of men'.
To those I would say (as I have just stated in comment) :

So the everlasting love of God is ineffectual, you seem to be saying. What determines salvation is 'the choice that some make'. Who are better than the others who do not make 'that choice'. But we say (who believe in the sovereignty of God and in his election and predestination) that the choice is on the part of the Deity who made choice before the foundation of the world (in Christ, before the seed had done good or evil) and loved those whom he chose to love. Which love is effectual. The Creator loves all of his creatures. But that does not save. The everlasting love (of the Father) is particular and it is effectual.

But that God has already made choice does not prevent any one of us from seeking salvation and submitting to the gospel. Not at all. For Jesus Christ has already promised that 'he that cometh to me, I will in no wise cast out'.

I exhort therefore, that, first of all, supplications, prayers, intercessions, and giving of thanks, be made for all men; For kings, and for all that are in authority; that we may lead a quiet and peaceable life in all godliness and honesty. For this is good and acceptable in the sight of God our Saviour; Who will have all men to be saved, and to come unto the knowledge of the truth.  [1 Timothy 2:4 KJV]


This answer is self-contradictory.  In the first half you say that salvation depends on God's sovereign choice and in the second half you say that all men can seek salvation.  Does this mean that those not chosen by God can still seek salvation.? Lastly, how would such be able to seek salvation of the need to do so is from God alone?

@Dottard For any person to be saved, they have to come to the knowledge of the truth. Yet Jesus rebuked religious leaders who thought they would be saved by knowing the scriptures so well, yet he told them to search the scriptures so that they would come to him for life: Jn.5:39-40. Knowledge of the truth means knowing Jesus, who he really is, then he reveals the Father to them. Until that happens, it's not saving truth that's known. And it's the heart of those searching that distinguishes head knowledge from knowing the Saviour. People resist God's will until that happens, so, no contradictio

Lots of people strive to seek salvation but look in the wrong places: “Strive to enter in at the strait gate for many will seek to enter in and shall not be able” Lk.13:24. Many don’t realise that Christ is the entrance, the door for the sheep. Others won’t humbly come to the Christ of scripture, preferring a non-judgmental, lovey-dovey version. But when they cry out to God, realising the hopelessness of their sinful state, he reveals Christ to them: Jn.6:40 & 44; 14:6 & 10:7-9. It’s all about what is in their hearts, and only God knows that.

+1 for sticking to a doctrine that does not diminish God‘s freedom from our inability to understand him. Human nature really does hate this doctrine.

@Dottard, I agree and I have been thinking about how to reconcile the line between taking control of your life and letting God take control of it, those two have boggled my mind a lot.

Thee is a Bibe verse that says the number of Gentiles to be saved is pre-determined and God awaits that number to fill up so He can lift up His Spirit[Holy Sprit] so the devil can go out and deceive the world. Pre-destination is s real as Jesus telling Peter he will deny him three times, he knows, both our eternal destinies and our earthly destinies

The reconciliation of these seemingly opposing doctrines comes in abandoning man made definitions of and application of philosophical terms and in just bringing to bear what the Scriptures say.  This is not to say that there is not difficulty in grasping both God's sovereignty and human choice but, if both are taught then both must be held:  Truths in tension.
Predestination
This word is taken by some to indicate that God has decided to forgive Jimmy but not Johnny, regardless of what either of them have done, can do or desire.  That from the foundation of the world God has determined to actively give Jimmy the ability to respond to the Gospel and to actively withhold that same ability from Johnny.

For whom he did foreknow, he also did predestinate to be conformed to the image of his Son, that he might be the firstborn among many brethren. Moreover whom he did predestinate, them he also called: and whom he called, them he also justified: and whom he justified, them he also glorified. - Romans 8:29-30

What the Bible says about predestination, however, is different.  The term is used to describe how those who have responded to the Gospel can be assured of the completion of their salvation.  They are said to be predestined to conformity with Christ's image.  It nowhere says that they are predestined to believe just that, having believed, they are assured of God completing what He has begun in them.
The word is used 6 times.  Twice here in Romans, once at Acts 4:28 in recalling how the evil actions of men against Jesus were in accord with God's will, once at 1 Cor.2:7 regarding God's wisdom unto our glory, then in Ephesians 1:5 and 11 where our adoption and inheritance are predestined.  All of these occurrences have to do with what is guaranteed, what is predestined, for those who have believed; not with the belief itself.
Election
This word is often mistakenly conflated with predestination in it's unbiblical connotation (that of active, absolute determinism) and much confusion arises here.  What is indicated in Romans 8 is that the ones that are predestined to conformity to Christ are the ones that God foreknew and, having foreknown and predestined them, He then called, justified, and glorified them.
This meshes very nicely with 1 Peter1:1-2, which says: "Peter, an apostle of Jesus Christ, to the strangers scattered throughout Pontus, Galatia, Cappadocia, Asia, and Bithynia, Elect according to the foreknowledge of God the Father, through sanctification of the Spirit, unto obedience and sprinkling of the blood of Jesus Christ: Grace unto you, and peace, be multiplied.".
Election is according to God's foreknowledge and happens through the sanctification of the Spirit.  Apparently it is very common to believe that perfect, complete Divine foreknowledge eradicates human choice and turns everything into predestination but that is not so (a somewhat long read but well worth the effort).
God knows the end from the beginning (with no limitations given).  If we take this at face value then the biblical doctrine of Election is all tied up in the very act of creation itself.  Prior to creating, God already foreknew everything ... including every choice of every person who would ever live.  Those He would save were foreknown from then; chosen (elect) in Christ from the foundation of the world according to the foreknowledge of God.  He did not cause those foreknown choices in any way other than that He created people with the faculty of choice.
The Gospel
It is the power of God unto salvation to everyone that believes.  Conversely, it is not the power of God unto salvation to those who do not believe.  What is this power?  Some would say it is God having given Jimmy the ability to respond to the Gospel and be saved, but that is not what is being said.  Paul does not say it is the power of God to believe.  He says it is God's saving power to those who believe.  Believe here is active tense ... it is the individual who actively believes, not passively receives the ability to believe.

He came unto his own, and his own received him not. But as many as received him, to them gave he power to become the sons of God, even to them that believe on his name: John 1:11-12

Received Him not, received Him, believed on His name:  All three are active tense.  It is the individual who actively receives or does not receive.  Those actively receiving, actively believing on His name, are given power to become sons of God.  The Spirit of God indwells such and they are predestined to be conformed to the image of Christ.  They are born "not of blood, nor of the will of the flesh, nor of the will of man, but of God.".
It is the will of God that the Son of Man would be lifted up, just as Moses lifted up the serpent in the wilderness, such that everyone who (actively) believes would be born again unto eternal life.  I can find no indication in the Numbers 21 account that God caused some to look and prevented others.  The way of forgiveness, the bronze serpent, the foreshadowing of the Son of man, was lifted up unto all and a legitimate choice was offered.
Be wary of a Gospel which says, "If God gives you the ability to believe on the Lord Jesus Christ you will be saved" because the flip side of that Gospel is, "If God does not give you the ability to believe on the Lord Jesus Christ you have been doomed from the start."  The lifting up of the Son of man gives everyone the ability to choose.  His saving power is sufficient for all and only effectual to those who actively believe.  God has simply not commanded all men everywhere to repent and then withheld the ability to repent from most.
Such a choice to look, to believe, is not that of a person saving himself or meriting salvation.  It is the desperate act of a person with no other recourse; a sinner laid bare before holiness of God, justly serpent bitten and dying.  If a drowning man grabs onto the rescue swimmer has he, in so grasping, saved himself in any way?  And if he refuses to acknowledge that he is drowning, will he reach for the rescue at hand?
*Footnote:  I am aware that many people have had a conversion experience such that it is difficult to feel that there was any choice on their part involved.  The conviction of the Holy Spirit of sin, righteousness, and judgement being so profound that choosing to not call on the Name seems impossible.  Such is my story as well but experience must not interpret Scripture.  It must be remembered that "those He foreknew, He predestined and those he predestined, He called".  Some say this calling is the proof text of Calvinism but that can only be true if God's foreknowledge is not a foreknowledge including every human choice.  If God is allowed to be big enough to actually foreknow literally everything then He is big enough to call all those whom He foreknows will respond.  That's the progression given in Romans 8:  Foreknow, predestine, call, justify, glorify.  Election is according to the foreknowledge of God.  Is He big enough to foreknow every human choice?  I believe the Bible teaches that He is at least that big.
This is not easy believism, as some might say.  One is not saved by claiming to believe but by actually believing.  It is painful to agree with what God says about oneself, about rebellion and slavery to sin, about revelry in the dark and hatred of the light, about no good thing dwelling within, about being justly condemned.  It is painful unto the abhoring of the self and repentance.  It is painful unto calling on the name of the Lord, unto the crucifixion of self.  Today, if you hear His voice, do not (actively) harden your heart!  Which entreaty clearly shows that hardening of one's heart or not is a choice for which we are responsible.
